# Regular expression to match hyphenated words (kebab-case)

Tags: php, regex, string, text-extraction, kebab-case

How can I extract hyphenated strings from this string line?

```
ADW-CFS-WE CI SLA Def No SLANAME CI Max Outage Service
```

I just want to extract "ADW-CFS-WE" from it but has been very unsuccessful for the past few hours. I'm stuck with this simple regEx "(.*)" making the all of the string stated about selected.

Answer (score 17):

You can probably use:

```
preg_match("/\w+(-\w+)+/", ...)
```

The `\w+` will match one or more consecutive characters which may be letters, numbers or underscores (one word). And the second group `( )` will match one or more repetitions of: a hyphen followed by a sequence of one or more characters which may contain letters, numbers or underscores.

The trick with regular expressions is often specificity. Using `.*` will often match too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "ADW-CFS-WE X-Y CI SLA Def No SLANAME CI Max Outage Service";
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]+-[A-Z-]+/', $input, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
  echo $matches . "\n";
}
```

Note that this solutions assumes that only uppercase A-Z can match. If that's not the case, insert the correct character class. For example, if you want to allow arbitrary letters (like a and Ä), replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{L}`.

Comment: Don’t write `[A-Z]` when `\p{Lu}` is available.

Comment: @tchrist I assumed his IDs are all upper-case latin characters and that he **doesn't** want to match a `ℝ-äe`. In general, I agree, but in this case, I think `[A-Z]` is perfectly adequate.

Comment: The problem is that `\p{Lu}` is safe no matter what the character set, but `[A-Z]` breaks on most of them.

Comment: @tchrist Could you elaborate? I was under the impression that `preg_match(/[a-Z]/, $_POST['input'])` matches a user input of `A` if the whole page uses, say, UTF-8.

Comment: Oh gosh.  False positive: `^`, `_`, etc.  False negative: `Å`, `É`, `Æ`, `Ñ`, etc.

Comment: @tchrist Not a single one of these inputs matches `/[A-Z]/`, so I'm not sure how there could be any false positives. And as far as I can test, `Å` does not match, which is quite intentional and may be useful if the match should capture only latin characters (for, say, an airport code).

Comment: Å is `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE`. That makes it a Latin letter, you know.  And you wrote `[a-Z]` in your comment, which I took for `[A-z]`, which is the false positives.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry, let me rephrase that: What if I want to match only ABCD..Z (like international airport codes) and am using `[A-Z]` (sic, that lower-case was a typo). Them I'm good, am I not?

Comment: Yes, then you are.  Best to put a comment in the code about that.  I still might use the intersection of `\p{ASCII}` and `\p{Lu}` myself to say "an ASCII upper case letter".  It’s how I’ve come to think of patterns and data these days.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks! Added a note to the answer mentioning ways how to match other characters than A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch every space free [^\s] words with at least an '-'.

The following expression will do it:

```
<?php

$z = "ADW-CFS-WE CI SLA Def No SLANAME CI Max Outage Service";

$r = preg_match('#([^\s]*-[^\s]*)#', $z, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern assumes the data is at the beginning of the string, contains only capitalized letters and may contain a hyphen before each group of one or more of those letters:

```
    <?php
    $str = 'ADW-CFS-WE CI SLA Def No SLANAME CI Max Outage Service';
    if (preg_match('/^(?:-?[A-Z]+)+/', $str, $matches) !== false)
        var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "ADW-CFS-WE"
    }
```

Comment: `[A-Z]` is always wrong. Even if it works on this dataset, it fails on 99+% of Unicode.  Get into the habit of matching `\p{Lu}` instead. Or, if you have a real regex language, use `\p{upper}`, which matches more than `\p{Lu}` does.

Comment: To say that `[A-Z]` is always wrong is always wrong.  It's only wrong when it's wrong.  Sometime you only want ASCII, and if you do this regex is just fine.