# preg_match for string - string

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Say I have an array:

```
$length =['pre-tied','self-tie','large','small'];
```

How would the preg_match command look like If I wanted to get values of 'string-string' format from the specific array?

```
foreach($length as $size)
 if(preg_match("/^[A-Z,-,A-Z]$/i",$size))
    do something
```

or

```
foreach($length as $size)
 if(preg_match("/^[A-Z,-,A-Z]$/i",$size));
    do something
```

Actually, I think the second one does not even make sense but since I am new to regular expressions I cannot be sure..

Comment: try `$length[0]`? (It is unclear what you are asking or trying to achieve)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer dognose, but I want to do it by using preg_match.

Comment: If your attempting to find a match in an array you can look at this question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831775/how-to-use-preg-match-in-array)

Comment: Do you have an _actual_ array – or do you have the _text literal_ `$length =['pre-tied','self-tie'];` as the content of a variable and want to do a regex search within _that_ …?

Comment: Also did you want to find only the value pre-tied or both pre-tied and self-tied? What other variations will exist in the array?

Comment: You definitely don't want to use the first one you listed with the comma.

Comment: You realize that the regexp you are asking for will obtain both pre-tied and self-tie.

Comment: Edited the question.. I hope it makes more sense now..

Comment: @IntegrityFirst, I edited the question so now it checkes if each item of the array matches the specific preg_match (the problem though is I don't know how to implement the preg_match).

Comment: Will there ever be something like 'string-' or '-string'. If you know it would be either 'string-string' or 'string' indicating that if it has a dash in the string it would be the exception. Why not use something like `strpos('-',$size) !== false`. It's more efficient anyways.

Comment: Thank you InterityFirst. srtpos() did not even pass through my mind. Makes things much simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When approaching regular expressions, the way I tackle these problems is starting from the very specific and looking for patterns and making it very general.

Simplest match:

```
 /^pre-tied$/
```

Matches e-t of pre-tied

```
 /^[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z]$/
```

Then if you are trying to match single-hyphen words, use one of the repeating operators (+, *)

```
 /^[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+$/
```

We can even make the regular expression more complex, like in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280104/regular-expression-to-match-hyphenated-words), but I think the final regular expression that I came up with should match both words in that array.

Comment: Thank you hrgui for the clear answer!